# JBoss Enterprise Application Server 6.1 with JBoss Plugin displays junk characters in Eclipse Console

Tags: eclipse, character-encoding, console, jboss-tools, jboss-eap-6

I've just installed JBoss Enterprise Application Server 6.1 in Eclipse
as stated above. When I start the server I get some junk characters in
the console on the right, next to the timestamps namely those squares
which look like this:

```
+--+
|00|
|1B|
+--+
```

What are they and how do I get rid of them getting them to display properly?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is bug in [JBoss Tools](https://issues.jboss.org/browse/JBIDE-14561), and should be fixed in JBoss Developer Studio 7 Beta1.
You could employ the workaround listed in that bug description, or you could add `-Dorg.jboss.logmanager.nocolor=true` in the server adapter startup arguments.